The default superclass, "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" not found on the Java Build Path. latest solution?
In my maven mvc project, inside index.jsp (The default superclass, "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet", according to the project's Dynamic Web Module facet version (2.3), was not found on the Java Build Path) error shows for  tag.
Try to change project fact --> runtime but not working.
